# some way to confirm an entry

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

i have a question which may or may not have an answer.

i have a cell, say A1, and if there is a "y" in A1, the values in A2 and A3 are added and the sum is in A4. If A1 is blank, A4 just has A3's value.
This is pretty simple to do in excel.

However, the question is, what can i use instead of inputting or deleting "y"? In my case, my data is a few thousand rows, and having this "y" option is making me add extra rows for no reason and would rather avoid.

Essentially, what i want is a way to use the value in A2, and find a way to command excel to update the A4 value if i want (by summing A2 and A3). Otherwise, it will keep on holding A3's value.

I have tried using a macro to update by changing font color and background color of A2 to signify a confirmation, but that will not work as excel doesnt perform calculations on font/color changes. If I hit F9, it will refresh and will work but this is too much hassle so I dont want this.

Guys please suggest something else for me! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following *Event Macro* in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A2 As Range
    Set A2 = Range("A2")

    If Intersect(A2, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        [A4] = [A2] + [A3]
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1:**

***First discard the previous macro*** and replace it with this one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim A2 As Range

    Set A2 = Range("A2")
    If Intersect(Target, A2) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Cancel = True
    [A4] = [A2] + [A3]
    A2.Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

It only affects double-click behavior in **A2**.  The code can easily be expanded to cover other cells or ranges.

**EDIT#2:**

In this version double-clicking **A2** confirms **A2**.  Double clicking **A3** un-confirms **A2**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim A2 As Range, boo As Boolean, A3 As Range

    Set A2 = Range("A2")
    Set A3 = Range("A3")

    If Not Intersect(Target, A2) Is Nothing Then
        [A4] = [A2] + [A3]
        A2.Font.Bold = True
        Cancel = True
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, A3) Is Nothing Then
        A2.Font.Bold = False
        [A4] = [A3]
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT#3:**

Using this macro extends the functionality to columns beyond column **A**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rw2 As Range, rw3 As Range, kolumn As Long

    Set rw2 = Range("2:2")
    Set rw3 = Range("3:3")

    kolumn = Target.Column
    If Not Intersect(Target, rw2) Is Nothing Then
        Cells(4, kolumn) = Cells(2, kolumn) + Cells(3, kolumn)
        Cells(2, kolumn).Font.Bold = True
        Cancel = True
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, rw3) Is Nothing Then
        Cells(2, kolumn).Font.Bold = False
        Cells(4, kolumn) = Cells(3, kolumn)
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36638/discussion-on-answer-by-garys-student-some-way-to-confirm-an-entry).

Comment: @Mokubai ..................I concur................

Comment: http://imgur.com/3jujHs5

Comment: Hi Gary's Student - after what we discussed, I now need to actually implement it in my actual spreadsheet, and I realised i am not capable to translate your code to work for a range. 

Please see the following screenshot, and my sheet looks like this:
http://imgur.com/3jujHs5 

Essentially I want to remove the "y" and use your double click code wherever there is the "additional" row. 

How I can use it here I am not sure so any help would be much much appreciated.

Comment: @rightanium I can assist you later......when I have more than a cell phone.

Comment: Thanks so much for your attention. If you can help when you can, that will be really good.

Comment: hi buddy - just following up to see if you had a chance to look at my stuff. thanks a lot.

Comment: @rightanium I am still here..............I **will** get back to you.

Comment: Any luck, sir? Sorry to be bothering you.

Comment: @rightanium  See my **EDIT#3**

Comment: Thanks for this. Although you said it work on any column, I only want it to work on columns starting from a certain place e.g. from column F onwards. Secondly, and more important, it needs to work only wherever it says "additional" for confirmation, and "baseline" for unconfirming. As per the image that I had uploaded. Hope you can understand. Thanks. It's coz some users use it and if it is adding things up on other rows, it will just destroy the whole sheet. Thanks

Comment: @rightanium  I don't understand the "additional" or "baseline" references.

Comment: No worries. If you see the image link that I had uploaded earlier, you will understand. The additional is just the A2 as per our first conversation, and baseline is just the A3. Hope this makes sense. The final number in the image is the same as A4.